# PIC16F684 A/D converter problem

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, adc, pic, converter

I'm having a problem with this circuit, it's my first time using the A/D converter.

The circuit turns on a relay when the battery connected to the A/D input reaches a voltage. The supply for this circuit is 220 VAC, then a 10 V transformer, rectified and filtered, and then a 7805.

If I plug the 220 V connector in first, it functions perfectly, it does everything. The problem is when I connect the battery first, because this is like feeding my circuit, and the PIC turns on. I measured the VCC and GND pin from the PIC and it has the same voltage as the voltage divider coming from the battery.

So my problem is that I can't plug in the battery first (the battery voltage goes through a voltage divider, so the maximum and minimum voltage of the battery is from 1 to 5 V).

Another thing, if anyone has an idea: if I connect a larger voltage battery, the input of the PIC probably burns, so, what circuit for a voltage "cropper" can I use?

The clamp circuit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the code, but I don't think that it has anything to do with my problem.

```
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCIO  // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSCIO oscillator: I/O function on RA4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA5/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR Pin Function Select bit (MCLR pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown Out Detect (BOR disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal External Switchover bit (Internal External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define standby 1
#define detectar 2
#define carga 3
#define cargatemporizada 4
#define ecualizacion 5
#define fincarga 6
#define stop 7

/* Para realizar conversion:
 *      ADCON0bits.GO_DONE=1; ARRANCA CONVERSION
 *      while (ADCON0bits.GO_DONE == 1 ) {} ESPERA A QUE SE REALICE LA CONVERSION
 *      int bits_low= ADRESL; se guardan los resultados
 *      int bits_high= ADRESH;  se guardan los resultados
 *      int res=(ADRESH<<8)+ADRESL;
 */

/*  tiempo de clock: 0,065025
        1 Segundo=15 ciclos de clock
        30 segundos=461 ciclos de clock
        1 minuto = 900 ciclos de clock
        1 hora = 54000 ciclos de clock
        3 horas = 162000 ciclos de clock
        200 segundos= 3075 ciclos de clock
        200 segundos= 3075 ciclos de clock
 */

//SALIDAS
#define RELE RC5
#define ledlin RC4
#define ledbat RC3
#define ledcar RC2
#define ledfin RC1
#define ledecu RC0
//SALIDAS

//ENTRADAS
#define STOP RA5 
#define ECUA RA4
#define DATOS RA2 
//ENTRADAS

#include <xc.h>

void main(void) 
{
    OPTION_REG=0b10000111;    
    INTCON=0b00000000;  
    //OSCCON=NOUSE IRCF2 IRCF1 IRCF0 OSTS(1) HTS LTS SCS; para modificar CLOCK, POR DEFECTO=4MHZ
    TRISA=0b00110100;
    TRISC=0b00000000;
    CMCON0 = 7;
    PCON=0b00000000;
    WPUA=0b00000000;
    ANSEL=0b00000100;
    ADCON0=0b10001000;
    ADCON1=0b01110000;
    ADCON0bits.ADON=1;
    ledlin=0;
    ledbat=0;
    ledcar=0;
    ledfin=0;
    ledecu=0;
    RELE=0;
    int res=0, temporizador=0, tempmaximo=0, temporizadorb=0, bateriamin=561, bateriamax=940, bateriamed=836, bits_low=0, bits_high=0;
    unsigned char estado=1, estado_anterior=0, estadocambio=0, a=0,b=0, c=0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (T0IF == 1)
        {
            T0IF = 0;
            TMR0 = 0;
            if (temporizador > 0)
            {
                temporizador--;
            }
            if (tempmaximo > 0)
            {
                tempmaximo--;
            }  
            if (temporizadorb > 0)
            {
                temporizadorb--;
            }  
        }
        
        if (estado != estado_anterior)
        {
            estado_anterior = estado;
            estadocambio = 1;
        }
        else if (estado == estado_anterior) estadocambio = 0;
 
        if (estado == standby)
        {
            if (estadocambio == 1)
            {
                __delay_ms(1500);
                ledlin = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                ledlin = 0;
                ledbat = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                ledbat = 0;
                ledcar = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                ledcar = 0;
                ledfin = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                ledfin = 0;
                ledecu = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                ledecu = 0;
                ledfin = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                ledfin = 0;
                ledcar = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                ledcar = 0;
                ledbat = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                ledbat = 0;
                ledlin = 1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                ledlin = 0;
                __delay_ms(1500);
                ledlin = 1;
                ledbat = 1;
                ledcar = 1;
                ledfin = 1;
                ledecu = 1;
                __delay_ms(1000);
                ledlin = 0;
                ledbat = 0;
                ledcar = 0;
                ledfin = 0;
                ledecu = 0;
                __delay_ms(1000);
                ledlin = 1;
                ledbat = 1;
                ledcar = 1;
                ledfin = 1;
                ledecu = 1; 
                __delay_ms(1000);
                ledbat = 0;
                ledcar = 0;
                ledfin = 0;
                ledecu = 0;
                temporizador = 60;
            }
            if (temporizador == 0)
            {
                ADCON0bits.GO_DONEb = 1;
                while (ADCON0bits.GO_DONE == 1) {} 
                int bits_low = ADRESL; 
                int bits_high = ADRESH;
                int res = (ADRESH<<8) + ADRESL;
                if ((res > bateriamin) && (res < bateriamax) && (a == 0))
                {
                    ledbat = 1;
                    temporizadorb = 60;
                    a = 1;
                }
                if ((temporizadorb == 0) && (a == 1))
                {
                    estado = carga;
                    a = 0;
                }
            }   
        }
        else if (estado == carga)
        {
            if (estadocambio == 1)
            {
                ledcar = 1;
                RELE = 1;
                tempmaximo = 540000;
            }
            
            ADCON0bits.GO_DONE = 1;
            while (ADCON0bits.GO_DONE == 1) {} 
            int bits_low = ADRESL; 
            int bits_high = ADRESH;
            int res=(ADRESH<<8) + ADRESL;
            
            if ((STOP == 1) || (tempmaximo == 0) || (res > bateriamax))
            {
                estado = stop;
            }
            if ((res > bateriamed) && (res < bateriamax))
            {
                estado = cargatemporizada;
            }
            if (ECUA == 1)
            {
                ledecu = 1;
                a = 1;
            }
        }
        
        else if (estado == cargatemporizada)
        {
            if (estadocambio == 1)
            {
                temporizador = 16200;
            }
            if ((temporizadorb == 0) && (ledcar == 1))
            {
                ledcar = 0;
                temporizadorb = 15;
            }
            if ((temporizadorb == 0) && (ledcar == 0))
            {
                ledcar = 1;
                temporizadorb = 15;
            }
            
            ADCON0bits.GO_DONE = 1;
            while (ADCON0bits.GO_DONE == 1) {} 
            int bits_low = ADRESL; 
            int bits_high = ADRESH;
            int res=(ADRESH<<8) + ADRESL;
            
            if ((STOP == 1) || (tempmaximo == 0) || (res > bateriamax))
            {
                estado = stop;
            }
            
            if (temporizador == 0)
            {
                estado = fincarga;
            }
            
            if (((ECUA == 1) || (a == 1)) && (b == 0))
            {
                b = 1;
                ledecu = 1; 
                temporizador = temporizador + 162000; // 3 horas mas
            }
        }
        else if (estado == fincarga)
        {
            if (estadocambio == 1)
            {
                ledfin = 1;
                ledbat =0;
                ledcar= 0;
                ledecu = 0; 
                RELE = 0;                
            }
        }
        else if (estado == stop)
        {
            if (estadocambio == 1)
            {
                ledfin = 1;
                ledbat = 0;
                ledcar = 0;
                ledecu = 0; 
                RELE = 0;
            }
            if ((temporizadorb == 0) && (ledlin == 1))
            {
                ledlin = 0;
                temporizadorb = 15;
            }
            if ((temporizadorb == 0) && (ledlin == 0))
            {
                ledlin = 1;
                temporizadorb = 15;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The resistor values are missing. Please add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit is likely latching up because the battery tries to power-up the processor via **RA2/AN2** input.
Since the battery is a very slowly-varying DC voltage, try adding a 10k resistor in series. AN2 input resistance is quite high, so the DC voltage drop across this external resistor should be insignificant.
For further protection a clamp diode or zener diode might be added to, to prevent over-voltage on that input pin, but the 10k resistor alone may be sufficient to stop latch-up.

---

**edit**
Connecting the battery **before** connecting Vdd voltage from 7805 will try to power-up the 16F684 via RA2/AN2. Some precaution should be taken to prevent start-up with too-low Vdd. The 16F684 includes *brown-out-reset* hardware to ensure clean power-up. Take advantage of this feature.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9AXrF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I mean, you give me the solution for every problem that i had! Really thank you for your time, its means a lot for me!!! i added a circuit in the post, can you tell me if you think its okay? i saw it in the datasheet of the pic. It doesnt says about what diode to use, you recommend me to use bat54 both? Thank you!

Comment: Samuel, the datasheet ADC circuit you refer to **resides inside the 16F684** in an attempt to prevent latch-up that you're likely experiencing. This internal circuitry should only be expected to clamp very short-term weak transients. Edits have been added to this answer (please re-read). The externally-added BAT54 should conduct *before* the internal clamp diode since its forward voltage is lower than 0.6V.